# Magento 2.2.5: Error when trying to update any category

Tags: magento2, category

Whenever i try to update anything in a category being: description, design, seo etc. i get greeted with this nice error:

> Element 'referenceBlock': This element is not expected. Expected is one of ( referenceContainer, container, update, move, head, body ).Line: 1

This has only just started appearing for an unknown reason.
I havent updated magento recently since it stopped working. And am on 2.2.5 running php 7.1.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please check under design tab at category settings if you added any custom layout updates. If yes then replace `referenceBlock` with `referenceContainer` and try to save it. Check below screenshot for your reference:

[image]

Comment: Great! It's my pleasure that I was able to help you out. Keep helping other community members :)